# docker-compose: make container available under subdomain

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, debian

I want a container to be reachable as `host-a` as well as `sub.host-a` from another container `host-b` in the same network.

What I tried in my `docker-compose.yml` (inspired by [this blog post](https://andrewtarry.com/docker_compose/)):

```
version: '3'
services:
  host-a:
    networks:
      my_network:
        aliases:
          - sub.host-a
    ...

  host-b:
    networks:
      - my_network
    ...

networks:
  my_network:
```

Resolving `host-a` works from `host-b`, but resolving `sub.host-a` does not.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: It would be safer to explicitly state `driver: bridge` on the last line of your `docker-compose.yml` (if this is the default you are waiting for).

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Thanks for your comment. Yet being new to docker(compose) I fail to see the connection to my question. What I want is for the other hosts on the same network to have not only `host-a` but also `sub.host-a` point to the first container.
Or is this just a general, unrelated hint?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference) says `The default driver depends on how the Docker Engine you’re using is configured, but in most instances it is bridge on a single host and overlay on a Swarm.` And the blog post you are referring to use `driver: bridge`. So it worth trying to use `driver: bridge` at the end of your `docker-compose.yml` file, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad.

Actually, the `aliases` are working exactly as expected: The first container **can** be accessed from other containers as `sub.host-a`.

No other changes needed.